# why am i getting this segmentation fault when trying to access a struct using a pointer?

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am trying to learn the nested structure. When I access it using a structure variable it works fine.
But when I try to access it using a pointer it says a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Vehicle {
    int eng;
    int weight;
};

struct Driver {
    int id;
    float rating;
    struct Vehicle v;
};

void main() {
    struct Driver *d1;
    d1->id = 123456;
    d1->rating = 4.9;
    d1->v.eng = 456789;

    printf("%d\n", d1->id);
    printf("%f\n", d1->rating);
    printf("%d\n", d1->v.eng);
}
```

Comment: your getting segmentation fault because you did not allocate memory for the struct Driver! you can allocate memory on the stack (by declaring Driver, `struct Driver d; struct Driver* pd=&d;`) or on the heap by calling `malloc`. `struct Driver* pd = malloc(sizeof(struct Driver));`

Answer (score 4):

You must initialize the pointer to an address of valid buffer before dereferencing that.

For example:

```
void main(){
    struct Driver d; /* add this */
    struct Driver *d1;
    d1 = &d; /* add this */
```

Also I suggest you should use standard `int main(void)` in hosted environment instead of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, unless you have some special reason to use non-standard signature.

Answer (score 1):

You used pointer `d1` without initialising it.

You need to initialise it first, for example with `malloc`:

```
struct Driver *d1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Driver));

if(NULL == d1)
{
    perror("can't allocate memory");
    exit(1);
}

// ... using d1

free(d1);
return 0;
```

Comment: you should check `malloc()` return value and calling `free()`. please add this to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the pointer before you can access what it points to.  Here's one way to fix it:

```
    struct Driver data;
    struct Driver *d1 = &data;
    d1->id=123456;
    d1->rating=4.9;
    d1->v.eng=456789;

    printf("%d\n",d1->id);
    printf("%f\n",d1->rating);
    printf("%d\n",d1->v.eng);
```

Note the addition of `data`, and the initialization of `d1` to point to it.  When run, it produces:

```
123456
4.900000
456789
```

Another way to initialize it would be to use dynamically allocated memory via `malloc`, in which case you would later free the memory that you allocated.